# No SVN (subclipse) menu in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm trying to integrate subclipse to eclipse-indigo, but it doesn't work.
(Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Indigo Service Release 2 
Build id: 20120216-1857 )

I installed the plugins shown on the picture. http://im.bilderkiste.org/9133619995455/Eclipse_Installation_Details_2012-05-05_08-10-37.png

But after installation and restart, there is no integrated menu or something else with SVN in Window -> open perspective/view or new -> other.
http://im.bilderkiste.org/9133620001047/Open_Perspective_2012-05-05_08-13-01.png

Please, can somebody help?

Comment: You are with just a bit newer version of subclipse compared to mine. Also I have not installed anything of the subversive things. It is either a bug with the newest version, or with something from subversive. I suggest you try reinstalling without selecting the subversive options.

Comment: You have both Subclipse and Subversive installed.  Usually that gives you 2 SVN perspectives not 0.  I would still remove one of them as my first step.  Maybe check your error log.  Even though they show installed, for the perspective to not appear the plugin cannot be loading.

Comment: You could also try to start eclipse once with "-clean" commandline option so it re-reads plugins, maybe then it will find the new plugins?

Answer (score 1):

If your project has already been checked out by some other client e.g. Tortoise SVN client then in Eclipse 
Right Click -> Team -> Share Project -> SVN -> Next -> Finish.

Answer (score 0):

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Popular -> Install Subclipse
Select all packages, accept license.
After install subclipse restart eclipse.
Than Windows -> Open Perspective -> 
SVN Synchronizing (for create connection to repos)
and
Team Synchronizing (for commiting, updating, merging and other)